# Interactivity Interaction Request Error

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

Just want to ask regarding to the error I encountered. In raising a `interactionrequest`, first the program run according to my code but if I close the interaction request for several times, following error will occur

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception'
>   occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: The operation completed successfully

To make help you understand here's my code:

**View Model**

```
 public class FinanceShellMainViewModel : BindableBase 
    {
     public InteractionRequest<LoginNotification> LoginFormShow { get; private set; }
     public DelegateCommand WindowLoaded { get; set; }

        public FinanceShellMainViewModel()
         {
             WindowLoaded = new DelegateCommand(SystemOnload);
             LoginFormShow = new InteractionRequest<LoginNotification>();
         }



      private void SystemOnload()
       {
           OpenAuthenticateUser();
       }



private void OpenAuthenticateUser()
       {
           LoginNotification Auth = new LoginNotification();

           Auth.Title = "Login Form";
           this.LoginFormShow.Raise(Auth, retval => 
           {
               if (retval != null &&  retval.IsLegit == true && retval.Confirmed)
               {

               }
               else 
               {
                   OpenAuthenticateUser();
               }

           });

       }

 }
```

Once the model view is loaded, the PopupWindowAction will appear

**View**

```
 <Window x:Class="FINNANCE_PROGRAM.Views.FinanceShellMain"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        Title="FinanceShellMain" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:intr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
         prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
         Height="500" Width="800"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:FINNANCE_PROGRAM.Views.ViewNotifications">

    <intr:Interaction.Triggers>

        <intr:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <intr:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding WindowLoaded}"/>
        </intr:EventTrigger>

        <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding LoginFormShow, Mode=OneWay}">
            <prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True">
                <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                    <views:SystemLogin />
                </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
            </prism:PopupWindowAction>
        </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>



     </intr:Interaction.Triggers>

 </Window>
```

**LoginNotification**

```
  public class LoginNotification : Confirmation
    {
      public LoginNotification()
      {
          IsLegit = false;
      }
        public bool IsLegit { get; set; }
    }
```

I badly needed your help regarding this.
Any suggestion is HIGHLY appreciated.

**Stack Trace**

> WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.CreateWindowEx(int dwExStyle = {unknown}, string lpszClassName = {unknown}, string lpszWindowName = {unknown}, int style = {unknown}, int x = {unknown}, int y = {unknown}, int width = {unknown}, int height = {unknown}, System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef hWndParent = {unknown}, System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef hMenu = {unknown}, System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef hInst = {unknown}, object pvParam = {unknown})    C#
>       WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper..ctor(int classStyle = {unknown}, int style = {unknown}, int exStyle = {unknown}, int x = {unknown}, int y = {unknown}, int width = {unknown}, int height = {unknown}, string name = {unknown}, System.IntPtr parent = {unknown}, MS.Win32.HwndWrapperHook[] hooks = {unknown})    C#
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.Initialize(System.Windows.Interop.HwndSourceParameters parameters = {unknown})   C#
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindow(bool duringShow = {unknown}) C#
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindowDuringShow()  C#
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Window.SafeCreateWindowDuringShow()    C#
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(object booleanBox = {unknown})   C#
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Window.Show()  C#
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()    C#
>       Prism.Wpf.dll!Prism.Interactivity.PopupWindowAction.Invoke(object parameter = {unknown})    C#
>       System.Windows.Interactivity.dll!System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerBase.InvokeActions(object parameter = {unknown})   C#
>       System.Windows.Interactivity.dll!System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTriggerBase.OnEvent(System.EventArgs eventArgs = {unknown})  C#
>       System.Windows.Interactivity.dll!System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTriggerBase.OnEventImpl(object sender = {unknown}, System.EventArgs eventArgs = {unknown})   C#
>       Prism.Wpf.dll!Prism.Interactivity.InteractionRequest.InteractionRequest`1.Raise(T context = {unknown}, System.Action callback = {unknown}) C#

Comment: Do you mean `interactionrequest`  as a library `System.Windows.Interactivity`?

Comment: @StepUp: `InteractionRequest` is an implementation of the Prism framework which uses (former Blend) Interactivity's `EventTrigger`, so yes and no :P https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/tree/master/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Interactivity/InteractionRequest

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of your exception.

Comment: hi sir @dymanoid heres its stack trace

Comment: My first solution is i've change my xaml code in order to solve the error

`<prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding LoginFormShow, Mode=OneWay}">
            <prism:PopupWindowAction>
                <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                    <views:SystemLogin />
                </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
            </prism:PopupWindowAction>
        </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>`

ive just removed the "IsModel" and "CenterOverAssociatedObject="True"

Comment: It might be a problem that you retrigger the interaction request from inside its raised handler. What if you don't close the popup if 'IsLegit` is `false`in the first place? That might be an improvement ux-wise, too, I'd hate a dialog that keeps popping up again after I click ok...